# Seaborn relplot y axis unorganized

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a dataframe similar to this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'time' : ['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00'],
    'count_a' : ['1', '7', '12', '3', '1', '8', '4'],
    'count_b' : ['3', '9', '5', '1', '3', '12', '1'],
    'count_c' : ['10', '5', '1', '15', '9', '3', '9']
    })
```

I am trying to create a line graph where x = time, and hue = ['count_a', 'count_b', 'count_c') so I used pd.melt and plotted:

```
df_melted = df.melt('time', var_name='counts', value_name='amount' )
sns.relplot(data=df_melted, x='time', y='amount', hue='counts', kind='line', marker='o')
plt.show()
```

which gave the following graph:
[image: test1]

What I need is for x='time' to still be in ascending order, and y='amount' to also be in ascending order.

Wondering if the data format is usable, and if so, how to order the y axis in ascending order.

Comment: You should turn your values into numbers, either with `.astype()` or `pd.to_numeric()`

Comment: BTW you don't need to melt here ... `sns.relplot(data=df.set_index("time"))` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the data you have are stored in strings, you'll need to convert them to actual numbers for them to plot correctly.

replace this line:

```
df_melted = df.melt('time', var_name='counts', value_name='amount')
```

with this:

```
df_melted = df.melt('time', var_name='counts', value_name='amount').astype({"amount": "int"})
```

Or, this:

```
df_melted = df.melt('time', var_name='counts', value_name='amount')
df_melted["amount"] = pd.to_numeric(df_melted["amount"])
```